# How to aggregate rows in a data frame based on string match in R? - regex

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, aggregate, data-cleaning

I'm working with a data frame that contains around 200 rows, I want to remove duplicated rows, adding together the values in the 'minutes' column. I'm fairly new to R and I haven't found a way to do this. Does it involve applying regex? I would really appreciate any solution!

The data frame I have looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Adam Tucker", "AdamTucker", "adam.tucker98@example.com", "adamtucker", "James Mirra", "JamesTMirra", "Sebastian F"), minutes = c(10, 3, 15, 2, 5, 1, 10)) 

                     name   minutes
              Adam Tucker      10
               AdamTucker       3
 adam.tucker98@example.com     15
               adamtucker       2
              James Mirra       5
              JamesTMirra       1
              Sebastian F      10
```

And the result I'm looking for would look like this:

```
       name    minutes
 Adam Tucker      30
 James Mirra       6
 Sebastian F      10
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Automatically recognising things like `"AdamTucker"` and `"a.tucker98@example.com"` as belonging to the same person is not the simplest thing. Do you have any other information you can use to identify these people? Otherwise some manual cleaning may be required.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't have any other information. I was guessing that a programmatic solution wouldn't be enough - particularly for that case - but because I'm just a beginner in coding I thought of asking around just in case. And by the way, how would you solve this example manually? Thank you!

Comment: I would edit the data manually (in the original csv file or whatever), adding a new column `cleaned_name` where I wrote out the name for each row in a standardized form. After that, you could do the aggregation automatically.

Comment: Oh, got it. AndI can see how the manual cleaning can become a headache for big data frames!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a master list with all unique names ? You can probably look at `pmatach` package in R , or use `sqldf`package to use LIKE function

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Adam Tucker", "AdamTucker", "adam.tucker98@example.com", "adamtucker", "James Mirra", "JamesTMirra", "Sebastian F"), minutes = c(10, 3, 15, 2, 5, 1, 10)) 
require(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where name LIKE '%adam%'")

#                       name minutes
1               Adam Tucker      10
2                AdamTucker       3
3 adam.tucker98@example.com      15
4                adamtucker       2
```

Then use levels to reassign each the same name or just add another column here with name say Adam Tuck as final version and merge with original data using name column as key.

Comment: I can ask for a master list with the final names! And I'll look up the pmatach package as well. Thanks!